# Agile Carousel with thumbnails issue

Tags: html, json, jquery, carousel

I'm using the [Agile Carousel](http://www.agilecarousel.com/) plugin on my site for a couple different slideshows.  The first one is at the top; I am not having a problem there.  My problem lies at the bottom (in the [About](http://www.opanitch.com/anatomidesign/clients/munchies/index.html#about) section) where I am trying to create a carousel with corresponding thumbnails.  I have it so that it creates the thumbnails and it scrolls through them, but once it get's to the end of the visible elements, it doesn't advance the slideshow to the next set of thumbnails.

My question is: How can I get the thumbnails to carousel themselves as the slideshow progresses?  Thanks in advance!

Here are some code snippets:

```
//Bottom Slideshow instantiation
$.getJSON("php/bottom/bottomShow_data.php", function(data)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#bottomSlide").agile_carousel({      
            // required settings
            carousel_data: data,
            carousel_outer_height: 525,
            carousel_height: 450,
            slide_height: 450,
            carousel_outer_width: 713,
            slide_width: 713,
            // end required settings

            transition_type: "fade",
            transition_time: 600,
            timer: 3000,
            continuous_scrolling: true,
            control_set_1: "previous_button,pause_button,next_button",
            control_set_2: "content_buttons"
        });
    });
});
```

JSON data snippet:

```
[
    { "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><img class='photo' src='../images/slideshow/bottom/1.jpg' alt='UGM 1' /></div>",
  "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img  src='../images/slideshow/bottom/1.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>" },
    { "content": "<div class='slide_inner'><img class='photo' src='images/slideshow/bottom/2.jpg' alt='UGM 2' /></div>",
  "content_button": "<div class='thumb'><img src='images/slideshow/bottom/2.jpg' alt='bike is nice'></div><p>Agile Carousel Place Holder</p>" },
....
14 objects total
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to modify the Javascript (agile_carousel.alpha.js), there's probably a better way (i.e. more efficient) to do this but this should work.

modify the add_selected_class function and add the following code:

```
var n = 0;

for ( n=1; n<=number_of_slides; n++) {
obj.find(".content_button_" + n).css("top", '0');
obj.find(".content_button_" + n).removeClass("thumb_show").addClass("thumb_hide");  
}
```

This is a crude way to do it but all this does is hides all the thumbnail buttons
For the thumb_show / thumb_hide classes you can use something like the following in your CSS:

```
.thumb_hide { display:none; position:relative; top: -50000px; left:0; z-index:0; opacity:0;}
.thumb_show { display:block; position:relative; top:0; left:0; z-index:20; opacity:1; }
```

the rest of the code for the add_selected_class functions just determines which set of 5 thumbnails to show depending on which slide is currently being displayed.

```
var $thumb_set_length = 5;
var $button_row_pos = 0;

$button_container_offset_top = Math.round(obj.find(".content_buttons_container").offset().top);                 
$current_button_offset_top = Math.round(obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).offset().top);

//Depending on the layout of your page and top padding/margin added to parent elements you will need to fiddle about with the values below to calculate where the buttons should be positioned.
$adjuster = Math.round( obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).height() / 2 );

$button_row_pos = ( $button_container_offset_top - $current_button_offset_top) * -1 - $adjuster + 26;

//if slide_num % 5 == 1 than this is the 1st of the 5 slides                

if ( (slide_num % $thumb_set_length) == 1 ) {

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+2)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+3)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+4)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");


obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+2)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+3)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+4)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");                    

}



//if slide_num % 5 == 2 than this is the 2nd of the 5 slides                

if ( (slide_num % $thumb_set_length) == 2) {

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+2)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+3)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");


obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+2)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+3)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

}


//if slide_num % 5 == 3 than this is the 3rd of the 5 slides                

if ( (slide_num % $thumb_set_length) == 3 ) {

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-2)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+2)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");


obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-2)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+2)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

}


//if slide_num % 5 == 4 than this is the 4th of the 5 slides                

if ( (slide_num % $thumb_set_length) == 4 ) {

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-3)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-2)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");


obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-3)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-2)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num+1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");

}


//if slide_num % 5 == 0 than this is the last of the 5 slides               

if ( (slide_num % $thumb_set_length) == 0 ) {

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-4)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-3)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-2)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).removeClass("thumb_hide").addClass("thumb_show");
obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-4)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");                    

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-3)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");                    

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-2)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");                    

obj.find(".content_button_" + (slide_num-1)).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");                 

obj.find(".content_button_" + slide_num).css("top", $button_row_pos + "px");
}
```

Comment: my thumb_hide is working but the buttons of slide 6 and 7 (if range = 5 slides) are not showing up, can't find them with correct positioning in the css as described